# flashMessage error in a controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller

here is my controller

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller{

/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $House = $this->getUser()->getHouse();

    if (!$House) {
        $this->addFlash('info', 'error');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('newHouse');
    }
    // ..
```

I check that my variable is assigned and if it is not, I display a message and I redirects. Before it worked well, but today I have this error ...

```
Attempted to call an undefined method 
named "addFlash" of class "appDevDebugProjectContainer".
```

the worst is that it works very well with the old method

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(....)
```

Someone Does he ever seen this error ? Thank you

*(version: 2.7.6)*

Comment: I would try simply clearing your cache with `php app/console cache:clear` and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same flash namespace ? I mean 'info' , what looked like your old code ? Just tested with 2.7.7 and it works as expected.

Comment: After update to 2.7.7, everything works... I dont understand but i can continue my project...